# Passing an image through getIntent() putExtra()

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am new to android studio and stack overflow so I may not make any sense but I want to pass some data from one activity to another. I have managed to do it through the putExtra() on the intent with all the text that I want passed to the activity. However, I do not know how to set a getIntent on an image that has to be produced with setImageResource().

FavActivity

```
                        Cursor cursor = (Cursor) mylist.getItemAtPosition(position);
                        String listName = cursor.getString(1);
                        String displayName = db.getName(listName);

if (!displayName.isEmpty()) {
                            String isleName = db.getIsle(listName);
                            String rowName = db.getRow(listName);
                            String locationImage = db.getLocationImage(listName);
                            Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(),MainActivity.class);
                            myIntent.putExtra("name", displayName);
                            myIntent.putExtra("isle", "Isle: " + isleName);
                            myIntent.putExtra("row", "Row: " +rowName);
                            myIntent.putExtra("image", locationImage);
                            startActivity(myIntent);
```

MainActivity

```
        textView.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("name"));
        textView3.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("isle"));
        textView4.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("row"));
```

Image location has to be set like this as its converting from database text

```
locationView.setImageResource(getResources().getIdentifier(locationImage, "drawable", getPackageName()));
```

How do I set an intent to do this?

Comment: what is value of locationImage?

Answer (score 1):

Store the image in a file and pass the file path through the intent to the other activty and you can access the image from that file path in the other activity

Answer (score 0):

Hiii, 
You can send an image in Base64 format and convert it to an image after receiving in next Activity.

Though make sure that you can send maximum `50kb` data using `Intents`. 
Otherwise, your app might misbehave on sending and receiving data.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass an image but I would suggest storing the image in Internal storage and pass them using Intent.

**As of API 24, there is 1 MB restriction else it would throw `TransactionTooLarge Exception` and may cost you too much memory**

Saving image to Internal Storage-

```
public String createImageFromBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
    String fileName = "myImage";//no .png or .jpg needed
    try {
        ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
        FileOutputStream fo = openFileOutput(fileName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
        // remember close file output
        fo.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        fileName = null;
    }
    return fileName;
}
```

and then pass that file name in **Bundle**

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(context
                    .openFileInput("myImage"));
```

An another example to be used

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setContentView(R.layout.my_layout);
    Bitmap bitmap = getIntent().getParcelableExtra("image");
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageview);
    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
 }
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, please could you tell me how I can do this when the image to be set depends on the row in a table it matches up to? The image isn't one image, it is five images where the location name is brought from the database depending on text inputted matching the row of that image

Comment: I will apply for each looping and set the image from 1 to 5 each row